# decoding key issue swift codable

Tags: swift, combine, codable

I have a function which I use to make api call but sometimes, I could get a decaying error and debugging this has been difficult. Below is my function, is there any way to maybe log or print the bad decoding key since I am using combine.

```
    func request<T>(with builder: BaseRequest, customDecoder: JSONDecoder) -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> where T: Codable {
        
        let encoding: ParametersEncoder = [.get, .delete].contains(builder.method) ? URLParameretersEncoder() : JSONParametersEncoder()
        customDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        var url: URL {
            var components = URLComponents()
            components.scheme = "http"
            components.host = builder.baseUrl
            components.path = "/api/v1" + builder.path
            
            guard let url = components.url else {
                preconditionFailure("Invalid URL components: \(components)")
            }
            
            return url
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 46.0)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = builder.method.rawValue
        builder.headers.forEach { key, value in
            urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
        if let token = tokenManager.token {
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }
        if let parameters = builder.parameters {
            guard let encoded = try? encoding.encode(parameters: parameters, in: urlRequest) else {
                fatalError()
            }
            urlRequest = encoded
        }
        self.log(request: urlRequest)
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .mapError { _ in .unknown }
            .flatMap { data, response -> AnyPublisher<T, APIError> in
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    return Fail(error: APIError.invalidResponse).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                self.log(response: response, data: data, error: nil)
                if (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) {
                    return Just(data)
                        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: customDecoder)
//                        .map {
//                            print($0)
//                            return $0
//                        } //added
                        .mapError {_ in .decodingError}
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    guard let errorResponse = try? customDecoder.decode(BaseResponse.self, from: data) else {
                        return Fail(error: APIError.decodingError).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }
                    return Fail(error: APIError.server(response: errorResponse))
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: you could try adding `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` just before `self.log(response: ...)`
 to print what you are really getting from your server, and track down the error from that. Sometimes a field needs to be optional, that is, it is not present in the data for that particular request.

Comment: Can you show the error you get (and on what line of code)?  To track down your problem, it would be easier to show us what your `T` structure is, and what json `data` you get from the server.

Comment: You are ignoring the **real** DecodingError, it would tell you exactly what’s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using this snippet to point to the bad decoding key which might help.

```swift
if let data = response.data {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let messages = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        print(messages as Any)
    } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
        print(context)
    } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
        print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
    } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let value, let context) {
        print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
    } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
        print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
    }
}
```

> Note that only include it for debugging purposes if decoding an API is not working as expected, and remove it after you have made necessary changes after seeing its output.

Comment: Note that, I am using `Alamofire` with custom generic decoding utils. Please make changes accordingly for the source of data with your specific setup based on your utility.